# Prove that the average degree in a tree is less than 2. Express the average degree as a function of $|V(G)|$.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that the average degree in a tree is less than 2.  Express the average degree as a function of $|V(G)|$.

I know that the average degree is the sum of the degree over all vertices divided by the number of vertices or:
$\frac {\sum\limits_{v \in V(G)} d(v)}{|V(G)|} $.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the degree over all vertices counts each edge twice—once at each vertex. So $\sum_{v \in V(G)} d(v) = 2 \lvert E(G)\rvert$.

And, every tree on $n$ vertices has how many edges?

Comment: So the Proof is something like this:
$\sum\limits{_v \in V(G)} d(v) = 2(n-1)= 2-2/n < 2$?

Comment: But how do I express the average degree using $|V(G)|$? @Kundor

Comment: Well, $n$ is just $\lvert V(G) \rvert$. So the average degree, as you noted, is $2 - 2/\lvert V(G) \rvert$.

Comment: Yeah, it is something like that, but the formula you have displayed in that comment is incorrect.  Specifically $2(n-1)\ne 2-2/n$, but i see that you got that from dividing by n, and that's correct.